# How to debug component/typescript code when running Protractor

Tags: angular, protractor, visual-studio-code

Most of the questions I've read so far only deal with trying to debug the unit tests / e2e tests when running Protractor / vscode (or rather how to make the breakpoints work in vscode)

In my case, I'm able to place breakpoints in my e2e tests and vscode have no issues with them, but the problem, once I'm *inside* the `it()` function, I have no clue how to access/inspect my components

I know e2e tests are not about components, but in this case, I was able to find a nasty bug that only e2e tests were able to catch, and I really need to inspect component variables to see what's going on

```js
    it('should do something with ProductComponent', () =>
{
    // Code...
        
    // Once I'm here, how can I inspect ProductComponent anyway??
}
```

where, for example, ProductComponent looks like this:

```js
@Component({
    selector   : 'app-product',
    templateUrl: './product.component.html',
    styleUrls  : ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent
{
    productId: number;
    productSKU: number;
    
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `browser.pause()` or `browser.explore()` methods. I think that `explore` fits more into your needs.

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.pause
http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.explore

```
import {browser} from 'protractor';

describe('suite', () => {
    it('test',() => {
        browser.pause();
        browser.explore();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Maciej, but I'm afraid I don't see how this would help me inspect the component(s)

Comment: I meant inspect component variable values, so as per the example I mentioned in my question, how to get the value of variable `productId`  (which belongs to `ProductComponent`)

Comment: Any update on that? Is browser.explore() that what you were looking for?

Comment: I'm still learning about the .explore(), I mean OK - it allows to pause and use list() to query the DOM, but so far I couldn't find a way to use it to inspect the components (some of my components have variables that are NOT rendered in the DOM, so DOM query won't help much in my case)

Comment: I am afraid that for such cases, you need to use unit tests, and it is impossible to inspect component so deeply with a protractor.

Comment: I did make some progress: I executed `ng e2e -sm`, paused the e2e test where I wanted using `browser.explore()`, I opened chrome dev tools, selected the component tag (ie. `<app-product>`), and finally executed `ng.probe($0)` in dev tools console tab, and voila! the component was fully available via `componentInstance`!

Comment: I still can't do step-by-step execution, but better than nothing I guess :)

Comment: Great. I am happy, that my answer was at least a bit helpful :)