# Debugging in VS Code using Jasmine framework (for Protractor)

Tags: visual-studio-code, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to debug in VS Code.
I've created the launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/conf/conf.js",
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using Jasmine and in my conf.js file (I'm using the file from the example when I installed Protractor), it starts with **exports.config = {** but it has 3 dots showing under it. When I click on the light bulb, it says "Convert to ES6 Module"

When I debug, it doesn't step into the code and just jumps to the end, even if I put breakdowns.

My conf.js file:

```
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  framework: 'jasmine',

  specs: ['../specs/horses.js'],

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  },
};
```

When I run: **protractor .\conf\conf.js** in the Terminal, it works fine.
I have a non-angular page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug protractor in VS CODE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54016095/how-to-debug-protractor-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I misunderstood your original question so here is a config that should work. Basically the `program` property needs to point to protractor and you pass your conf.js using the args `property`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
            "args": ["${workspaceRoot}/conf/conf.js"],
            "outFiles": [ "${workspaceRoot}/out/*.js" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

See [this article](https://medium.com/@ganeshsirsi/how-to-debug-protractor-tests-in-visual-studio-code-e945fc971a74) and this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54024350/10836734) for more information.

### Original Incorrect Ans

The config file is exporting an object and therefore only has one action that can be debugged and that is `export` of the config object itself. The properties you are exporting, like `specs`, `jasmineNodeOptions` are called at different times during the setup process when protractor launches and not actually doing anything at the time they are exported. If you introduced some executable code in a lifecycle hook, like a `beforeLaunch` or `onPrepare` and tried to debug that it would likely work as you are expecting

Comment: Thank you, but I don't quite understand what you mean. How do I call the spec file then?

Comment: Sorry maybe I misunderstood what you were referring to actually. Are you putting the breakpoints in executable spec files or are you putting them in your conf.js file? For instance in these [images](https://imgur.com/a/O9qMLNv) the breakpoints will not work in the conf file but should work for the spec.

Comment: It doesn't want to step into my spec file, even if I put breakpoints in the spec file.

Comment: @TinaCummins Ok, I've updated my answer. Can you try once more